# using variables in use schema/database commands

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to place my snowflakes into git repository. Some of the part are environment specific, like 
use schema analytics_dev   ### I will have to change this while deploying to qa and stuff.

I was thinking if could replace these with variable like this

set env='dev'
use schema analytics+$env

But this an error "SQL compilation error: syntax error line 1 at position 20 unexpected '+'."
How do I achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way, to append vars, and use as an identifier:

```
set env = 'dev';
set analytics_schema = 'analytics' || $env;
use schema identifier($analytics_schema);
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of options here:

```
set (min, max)=(40, 70);
select $min;
```

And this:

```
set var_artist_name ='Jackson Browne';
select getvariable('var_artist_name');
```

and more here:
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/session-variables.html

Comment: have you tried this in the context of use schema? it is working for me in the select query